# how to throw an IOException?

Tags: java, exception, io

```
public class ThrowException {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            foo();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
             if (e instanceof IOException) {
                 System.out.println("Completed!");
             }
          }
    }
    static void foo() {
        // what should I write here to get an exception?
    }
}
```

Hi! I just started learning exceptions and need to catch an expetion, so please can anybody provide me with a solution?
I'd be very grateful.
Thanks!

Comment: What is `foo` and how does it relate to `a`?

Comment: This is just basic Java syntax that any book or introduction to Java will teach you. I suggest reading some.

Answer (score 23):

```
static void foo() throws IOException {
    throw new IOException("your message");
}
```

Comment: should I write this in the foo method?

Comment: Yes. If this line is reached an exception will be thrown.

Comment: note that the foo method must be declared to throw the exception.  otherwise you will get a compiler error

Comment: Oh - I forgot that. Thanks for the hint! I updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
try {
        throw new IOException();
    } catch(IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Completed!");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> I just started learning exceptions and need to catch an exception

To throw an exception

```
throw new IOException("Something happened")
```

To catch this exception is better not use `Exception` because is to much generic, instead, catch the specific exception that you know how to handle:

```
try {
  //code that can generate exception...
}catch( IOException io ) {
  // I know how to handle this...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to throw the exception from the `foo()` method, you need to declare it as follows:

```
public void foo() throws IOException{
    //do stuff
    throw new IOException("message");
}
```

Then in your main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        foo();
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Completed!");
    }
}
```

Note that, unless foo is declared to throw an IOException, attempting to catch one will result in a compiler error.  Coding it using a `catch (Exception e)` and an `instanceof` will prevent the compiler error, but is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
throw new IOException("Test");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code:

```
throw new IOException("Message");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps...

Note the cleaner way to catch exceptions in the example below - you don't need the `e instanceof IOException`.

```
public static void foo() throws IOException {
    // some code here, when something goes wrong, you might do:
    throw new IOException("error message");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```